Agora Push Notification Issue iOS
I need help finding the key to send in the push payload to send push notifications with Agora.
I am getting this payload -
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "You've got a new message",
      "body": "Message content here"
    },
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1
  },
  "e": {
    "custom": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
  },
  "m": "1368384083150400454", // Unique message ID.
  "t": "demo_user_1", // Sender ID.
}

But I also need the  "content-available": 1  in the aps and I am not able to find the key provided by Agora that I can set on the sender side.
Agora already provides em_push_mutable_content to add "mutable-content": 1 in the push payload but I am not able to find any pre-defined key for "content-available": 1 .
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
